# Windows 7 log in page freeze

Tags: windows-7

I have an old PC which after some time of inactivity get locked and when i try to unlock it, it s freeze on login page.

> CTRL - ALT - DELETE

Appears on the screen but i m unable to press any key, it does not work at all.

Also i could not access the PC remotely, so i restart the machine by pressing the button.

Any suggestions how to fix this issue or what may cause it?